# Changing to an SD card with more storage for android phone

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, internal-sd

My original SD card is formatted as storage so I am not sure if card readers can read and transfer data from it. So basically, I am looking for a way to switch SD card and preserve the files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is encrypted adoptable-storage you can only clone 1:1 partition size, so best is to backup everything before removing sd card. internal storage contains /sdcard (for that you can use MTP or adb pull) and obb data (you can use adb backup -obb -shared)

Comment: @alecxs What you write is true for an FDE encrypted adoptable storage. Have you ever encountered an FBE encrypted adoptable storage? They may exist since Android 9. From my understanding cloning and resizing of the adoptable sd-card should be easily possible as the partition is just a standard file-system like ext4. Would be interesting to see such an adopted sd-card with FBE.

Comment: @Robert AFAIK adoptable storage `sm` uses *dm-crypt* (and FBE on top which lead in the famous double encryption bug). Haven't seen any android 9+ supporting adoptable-storage in the end, newer devices have enough memory up to 256 GiB. btw i am not using encryption at all, i don't like the idea of hardware backed encryption, even a rugged outdoor phone can break